# Reset php pointer?

Tags: php, mysql, pointers, reset

I'm trying to do the following:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
    ...
}
...
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
    ...
}
```

but it doesn't work. The commands within the 2nd loop never run. I'm guessing that this has to do with the pointer of the mysql function, which has to be reset. If so, how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to go through mysql result twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439230/how-to-go-through-mysql-result-twice)

Comment: @MarkS, yup. I was searching for reset pointer and thats why I coulnd't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the function `mysql_data_seek`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

Though you should look at upgrading to not use mysql_* functions

Answer (score 3):

Avoid any functions starting with [`mysql_`](https://www.php.net/mysql_connect), they are deprecated. Using [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/pdo), you can do what you want like so:

```
$pdo = new PDO(/**/);                // [1]

$stmt = $pdo->prepare(/* query */);  // [2]
$stmt->execute();                    // [3]

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();           // [4]

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    //
}

foreach($rows as $row2)
{
    //
}
```

Guides for lines referenced above:

- `[1]` - [`PDO::__construct()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)
- `[2]` - [`PDO::prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)
- `[3]` - [`PDOStatement::execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)
- `[4]` - [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result2 = $result;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
    ...
}

...

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2){
    ...
}
```

Comment: @MarkM first you have to save $result into another variable