# Dropdown list only appears in the first table row

Tags: php, forms, html-table, dropdown

**Here is my query:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
$query = "SELECT * FROM employeerole ORDER BY role_id";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query);
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["last_name"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["role"]; ?></td>
        <td>
```

> Here is my code that includes a dropdown box in a table cell however, the data in the dropdown box only appears in the first row of the table *(as shown in screenshot below)*.
>
> Has this got something to do with the loop?

```
            <form action ="change.php">
                <select id="role" class="" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <?php while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $line['role_id']; ?>"><?php echo $line['role_name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="ConfirmDelete()" value="Delete account"</td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

**Screen shot of the table:**

[image]

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array reached the end, Next loop it won't have a next. You need to save data to an array and then loop it multiple times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go through mysql result twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439230/how-to-go-through-mysql-result-twice)

Comment: @FirstOne they're aleady using `MYSQLI_ASSOC` in `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` I have a feeling they're using a LIMIT that they're not showing. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The second code seem to be inside the loop from the top code. This means that it's calling fetch multiple times after it has reach the end, right?

Comment: @FirstOne could be. but this is failing `mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)` missing the `I`. It should read as `MYSQLI_ASSOC`. OP is mixing APIs and could be the reason.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Yep, that too. Good point... Haven't seen that

Comment: change to MYSQLI_ASSOC ..It's still the same though

Comment: Plus, it's hard to say because you're not showing us your full query and if there's a LIMIT in there, or which columns you've chosen.

Comment: @Fred-ii- just edited the question with my full query in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the result set `$result1` is exhausted in the first row itself. You have to adjust the result pointer to point to the beginning of the result set so that you could iterate through it again. Make use of `mysqli_data_seek()` function for this.

Add this line `mysqli_data_seek($result1, 0);` just after this line `..."this.form.submit()">` line.

So your code should be like:

```
// your code

        <form action ="change.php">
            <select id="role" class="" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <?php 
                    mysqli_data_seek($result1, 0);
                    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $line['role_id']; ?>"><?php echo $line['role_name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="ConfirmDelete()" value="Delete account"</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

// your code
```

Comment: You didn't read the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498160/dropdown-list-only-appears-in-the-first-table-row#comment56738082_34498160), right? ^^

Comment: @FirstOne Oh, that `MYSQLI_ASSOC` part. Fixed it.