# mysqli calling same data twice

Tags: php, mysqli

Can anyone explain a detailed answer as, am not able to found it on stackoverflow

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('log_errors',1);
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
   $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or 
  die(mysqli_connect_error());
    $query2 = "Select * from qualifications";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query2)or die (mysqli_error($link));   
    ?>
 <form>
  <table>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <select name="short_term_degree" id="short_term_degree" >
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <?php
                 while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  echo "<option 
  value='".$d['qual_id']."'>".$d['qualification']."</option>";
                  }
                  ?>
           </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <select name="short_term_course" id="short_term_course" >
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <?php
                 while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 echo "<option 
  value='".$d['qual_id']."'>".$d['qualification']."</option>";
                 }
                 ?>
           </select>
        </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

Result I Got

```
<select name="short_term_degree" id="short_term_course">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option value="268">Graduate</option>
 <option value="269">Mtech</option>
 <option value="353">Bachelor of Econimics</option>
</select>
<select name="short_term_course" id="short_term_course">
 <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

The Second Select Box Doesn't show any data What's the reason.

why do i require to use again  mysqli_query() before while OR mysqli_data_seek($result,0);
for getting result in select box

Comment: you can't use result set twice in while loop . you can store it in array and use it wherever you want

Comment: You could probably try and change the second `while ( $d` to something like `while ( $d2`.

Comment: @JYoThI is right. Change the code accordingly

Comment: i already mention above that 
why do i require to use again 
mysqli_query() before while OR mysqli_data_seek($result,0); 
for getting result in select box  **** why above fails can i get the explanation

Comment: Voting to close as unclear, given the comments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have already used the function replied to Dilip Patel answer below ,  expecting an explanation why above one fails why this is  happening

Comment: when first while loop run  the internal data pointer move ahead and reach the last data pointer . so while your trying to get data from that using second while loop . so there is no more data because .it's already reach last data pointer  . this is what the reason for failure @newbie and this is what is explained my below answer

Comment: Thanks @JyoThi For Explanation Is comment can be accepted as answer.

Comment: i updated my answer too @newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

The internal data point is still at the end when you try to use your second while loop. You have done nothing to reset it.

You can move it back to the start with `mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);`

**Update:**

when first while loop run the internal data pointer move ahead and reach the last data pointer . so while your trying to get data from that using second while loop . so there is no more data because .it's already reach last data pointer .

Comment: they're using the mysqli_ api, not mysql_. Edit: You edited ;-)

Comment: I wonder why your answer got a downvote? and a few others.

Comment: I wonder why in 2017 PHP users are still bluntly writing mysqli_data_seek($result, 0); inbetween HTML tags as though it's still  1997

Comment: Already mention in question why do i require mysqli_data_seek($result, 0)and  $result= mysqli_query($link,$query2) above the while loop to get my result. I am accepting for an explanation for cause

Comment: @newbie *"Already mention in question don't want to use mysqli_data_seek"* - Yet you wrote this in your question *"why do i require to use again mysqli_query() before while OR mysqli_data_seek($result,0);"* --- You're contradicting yourself.

Comment: Thanks @JyoThi For Update accepting the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Don't write same code twice use like this

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('log_errors',1);
  mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
   $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or 
  die(mysqli_connect_error());
    $query2 = "Select * from qualifications";
    $result=mysqli_query($link,$query2)or die (mysqli_error($link));  
    $options = "";
    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  $options .= "<option 
  value='".$d['qual_id']."'>".$d['qualification']."</option>";
                  } 
    ?>
 <form>
  <table>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <select name="short_term_degree" id="short_term_degree" >
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <?php
                 echo $options;
                  ?>
           </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <select name="short_term_course" id="short_term_course" >
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <?php
                 echo $options;
                 ?>
           </select>
        </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You have made a valid point but am using function as this is going to be on multiple pages and was am just curious about the reason of failure

Answer (score -1):

You can use mysqli_fetch_assoc twice in the following manner:-

[How to go through mysql result twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439230/how-to-go-through-mysql-result-twice)