# Iterating twice over same mysql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

I have a MySQL table of posts that looks like this:

```
| id | post                                 | parent |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 |    Hello world                       |      0 |
|  2 |    response to 1                     |      1 |
|  3 |    response to 1                     |      1 |
|  4 |    new opening post                  |      0 |
```

If a post is an opening post, the parent is set to 0.  If it's a reply to an opening post, its parent is a value of an ID.  I'm trying to fetch the table, print each opening post, then print responses underneath them indented.  This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row["parent"] == 0) {
        echo "" . $row["id"] . " | " . $row["post"] . "<br>"; }
                while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        if ($row["id"] == $row2["parent"]) {
                                echo ">" . $row2["id"] . " | " . $row2["post"] . "<br>"; }}}
```

I've been looking around on the internet for a solution for a while now to no avail; I've tried putting the mysql result into an array, but that didn't work either.  I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance!

This isn't a duplicate of [How to go through mysql result twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439230/how-to-go-through-mysql-result-twice) as I want keep going through the table instead of resetting after every OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go through mysql result twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439230/how-to-go-through-mysql-result-twice)

Comment: Could you put a few more data points in your table?  The two rows I see right now don't quite make sense.  If testmessage had `id` = `2`, it would make sense.  But with `id` = `0`,  I'm not sure that your data is structured correctly.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", can you elaborate please?

Comment: That's far to simplistic an approach for adjacency list.  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adjacency-list-tree/

Comment: @bugsy Is one of the issues that `$row['post']` isnt displaying?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With one statment create three array for id , post and parent then add each row data to these arrays and use to for loop to create the display result somthing like this code may be work.

```
$id=array();
$post=array();
$parent=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id[]=$row["id"];
$post[]=$row["post"];
$parent[]=$row["parent"];
}
for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++){
if($parent[$i]==0){
echo $parent[$i];
for($j=0;$j<count($parent);$j++){
if($parent[$j]==$id[$i]){
echo $post[$j];
}
}
}
```

Comment: Got it working.  Didn't think to create a separate array for each.  Thank you!