# Select Query Not working second time on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, pdo

> Select Query Not working second time on the same page...

**my_page.php**

```
require_once 'self_class.php';
$user = new USER();

$under_id = "0";
$get_categories_main = $user->runQuery('SELECT * FROM category WHERE Under LIKE :under ORDER BY Id ASC ');
$get_categories_main->bindParam(':under',$under_id);
$get_categories_main->execute();

if(isset($_GET['both'])){
    echo "Both";
    while($fetch_category_main=$get_categories_main->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo $fetch_category_main['Id'].") ".$fetch_category_main['Name']."<br />";
    }
}

echo "Main";
while($fetch_category_main=$get_categories_main->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $fetch_category_main['Id'].") ".$fetch_category_main['Name']."<br />";
}
```

---

When I visit **my_page.php** the result of the page is:

> Main
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> ........

**Great! the results are as expected...**

---

When I visit **my_page.php?both** the result of the page is:

> Both
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> ........

**OOOPS! the results are not as expected...**

**Expected Result is:**

> Both
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> ........
>
> Main
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> Id) Name
>
> ........

**Select Query Not working second time on the same page...**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439230/how-to-go-through-mysql-result-twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use **While** more than once in a query. To solve your problem, the correct one is to use the **While** only once and create an **array** and then call it in the **foreach**.

```
    require_once 'self_class.php';
    $user = new USER();

    $under_id = "0";
    $get_categories_main = $user->runQuery('SELECT * FROM category WHERE Under LIKE :under ORDER BY Id ASC ');
    $get_categories_main->bindParam(':under',$under_id);
    $get_categories_main->execute();

    while ($fetch_category_main = $get_categories_main->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $category[] = $fetch_category_main;
    }

    if(isset($_GET['both'])){
        echo "Both";
        foreach ($category as $key => $value) {
            echo $value['Id'].") ".$value['Name']."<br />";
        }
    }

    echo "Main";
    foreach ($category as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['Id'].") ".$value['Name']."<br />";
    }
```

You can also use the **For** as below;

```
require_once 'self_class.php';
$user = new USER();

$under_id = "0";
$get_categories_main = $user->runQuery('SELECT * FROM category WHERE Under LIKE :under ORDER BY Id ASC ');
$get_categories_main->bindParam(':under',$under_id);
$get_categories_main->execute();
$len =$get_categories_main->rowCount();

while ($fetch_category_main = $get_categories_main->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$category[] = $fetch_category_main;
}

if(isset($_GET['both'])){
echo "Both";
    for($x = 0; $x < $len; $x++) {
        echo $row = $category[$x]['Id'].") ".$category[$x]['Name']."<br />"; 
    }
}

echo "Main";
for($x = 0; $x < $len; $x++) {
    echo $row = $category[$x]['Id'].") ".$category[$x]['Name']."<br />"; 
}
```